# Why is my render washed out compared to viewport?

Tags: rendering

Ive gone through all the similar queries & tried all solutions but none seem to resolve my problem.
Heres my viewport
[image]
And heres my render
[image]
Most seemingly common was change Render Setting from Filmic to Standard, but made no difference

I render in Cycles but changed to Eeevee for the Ambient Occlusion and Bloom settings as also mentioned but again very little difference after turning on & tweaking those params.

I also tried some node editor changes on Overlay & Saturation as discussed in these forums but again no success

I also zoomed out (from the mars rover) to show this other maybe related rendered issue of clipping (washout is worse zoomed in) but I cant find any layered object there, perhaps its part of a diffuser for the sunset ?

Appreciate any assistance/insight please . If further details needed Ive also put the blend file here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amv6AWCUsu_YmitRFzSCBTdxmt0L?e=xKdaIW

Im starting to get frustrated as its been a few days now and Ive got all my modeling and animation done !!! its just not wysiwyg

TIA yap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some volumetric cube hidden in the viewport but enabled in the render, which gives your render a hazy washed out look. Disable it in render to remove it.[image]

Comment: +1 doh! so simple, yes that did it - much appreciated for a fresh set of eyes to see something I missed ! Thanks

Comment: @yetanotherpassword if it solved your problem, would you consider accepting the answer by pressing the check box :)